# Why does my foreach loop stop?

Tags: php, foreach

I created a foreach loop that was adapted from this [forum post](https://pods.io/forums/topic/populate-field-with-calc-results-based-on-other-fields/).

But it always stops after the first iteration.

Why is that happening?

It's supposed to check if the $field does not match anything in the $skip array, and then runs some code. But the code only runs on the first loop and then quits.

```
function bg_calculation_save ( $pieces ) {

    $skip = array('company_name', 'logo', 'screenshot', 'highlight_1', 'highlight_2', 'highlight_3', 'awards');

    foreach ($pieces[ 'fields' ] as $field => $value) {

        if (!in_array($field, $skip)) {

            // Calculate the points
            $points = bg_calculate_points($field) * bg_score_weights($field);   

            // Set the value of the "$field_points" field
            $pieces[ 'fields' ][ $field . '_points' ][ 'value' ] = $points;

            //If the field isn't being saved right now, add it to the list to be saved
            if (!in_array( $pieces[ 'fields_active' ])) {
                $pieces[ 'fields_active' ][] = $field;
            }
            return $pieces;
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pods_api_pre_save_pod_item_vpn', 'bg_calculation_save' );
```

Comment: Do a var_export of $pieces and post it in your question

Comment: You second `in_array(..)` is missing another parameter.

Comment: As you have an return statement in your foreach loop this can stop at any iteration. You may not have any of $skip values as $pieces first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `return $pieces;` outside of foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to executing the command if $field is found I think your condition should be

```
if (in_array($field, $skip))
```

With your condition

```
if (!in_array($field, $skip))
```

If on the first loop it's not in the array, the condition is true, it executes the statements and returns.  Therefore, the loop executes only ones.

If you're going for traversing all $field if it's not in_array you should remove the return statement.